# Using wildcard to address a directory in cmd

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I want to copy a directory and all the files within it that matches a particular name pattern i.e. starts with `r1_t(followed by any number of alphanumeric characters)` to the given location.

```
COPY "C:\PROJECTd\r1_t*\" "C:\PROJECT\BAK"
```

But apparently I can’t use wildcard to address a directory. So how can I achieve the above in a cmd batch file?

Comment: Find all directories matching the pattern and use a loop to run that command for each found instance.

Comment: You can use the `/D` option with the `FOR` command or the `DIR` command with the `/AD` switch to find the directories you want to copy then use the XCOPY or ROBOCOPY with those outputs.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to copy a directory and all the files within it that matches a name pattern

`copy` is for copying files not directories.

To copy directories use `xcopy` or `robocopy`.

Example:

```
xcopy "C:\PROJECTd\r1_t*" "C:\PROJECT\BAK" /s /i
```

Notes:

- **No** trailing `\` on the source directory name (otherwise you will get an `Invalid path` error).
- `/s` - Copy folders and subfolders.
- `/i` - If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.

Comment: I tried `C:\Users\maven>XCOPY "C:\Project\r1_t*" "C:\Project\BAK" /s /i` but it gives my `Cannot perform a cyclic copy` even though the destination folder isnt a child of the parent. why is that?

Comment: @Maven `BAK` is a **child** of `C:\Project`. Note in your question it isn't (you have ``C:\PROJECTd\`` as the source directory).